# Move a variable and operate on it

Tags: c++, c++11

Is the following code safe?

```
struct Foo {
   Foo bar() { return *this; }
} foo;

foo = std::move(foo).bar();  // is this safe?
```

I'm wondering if calling methods on an rvalue is safe.

Comment: Of course you can call methods on rvalues. Why shouldn't you?

Comment: There is a misconception that moved from objects "must be placed in a valid but unspecified state". This rule only applies to the standard library, to indicate what standard library operations on a moved from object are safe. In *general* code, it completely depends on how your class is defined. In this case, there is nothing "unsafe" about the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, calling a function on an rvalue is no more or less safe than calling it on an lvalue.

As for your specific code, no movement actually happens. `std::move(foo)` converts it into an rvalue, which is irrelevant to the call to `Foo::bar` since it doesn't care whether `this` is an lvalue or an rvalue. `bar` will return a *copy* of `foo`, which will then be copied back into `foo`.

The same thing would have happened if you hadn't used `std::move` at all. `std::move` doesn't actually *move* anything; it simply converts it into an rvalue which can participate in a move operation.

Your *real* question is this: for any type T which is moveable, is this legal:

```
T t;

t = T(std::move(t));
```

The answer is... maybe. The state of a moved-from object is exactly what the writer of `T` chooses for it to be. For most standard library types, it will be "valid-but-unspecified". This means that you can use functions that don't require preconditions, that will work regardless of the current state.

Move assignment is usually such a function, so that will generally work. Will it work for all types? There is nothing which guarantees that it will. It depends on how move support is implemented for each type. Some user-defined types can't achieve even a "valid-but-unspecified" state, which means the only thing you're allowed to do with a moved-from object is destroy it.

It all depends on how users choose to work. However, I would say that a type for which `t = T(std::move(t))` does not work (that is, yields undefined behavior) would be a very ill-behaved type.

Answer (score -3):

Not super safe, it is sometimes hard to break down, if it's just for a simple program/game it should be fine, I would recommend that you use a more secure code for a big program :)

Overall it's not going to be *too* bad if it breaks.

What I mean by super safe is that it can't handle a break, if you decide to use a function of a standard way of doing it (e.g: using Struct like you have)

Sorry I can't supply as much information as I can, I'm newish to struct
if anyone wants to edit my answer they can.

Thanks,

*~Coolq*

Comment: Why so many down? :(

Comment: Because this answer is incredibly vague, and completely useless.

Comment: Please, if it's vague, then post your own answer not discourage others.

Comment: That's not how this site works. We downvote bad answers, whether we have an answer ourselves or not.

Comment: I know, would you like to recommend how I could improve my answer?

I don't want a battle here.

Comment: @CoolqB Your answer raises more questions than it answers, what is "super safe"? What is "more secure code"? How would OPs code "break"?

Comment: Be specific. What is not "super safe" about it?

Comment: I'll edit my answer.